# jQuery AddClass to link not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add the class `ls-thumb-1` to an existing class of my link. But It does not work (nothing happens):

HTML

```
<div class="ls-thumbnail-wrapper" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div class="ls-thumbnail" style="width: 1200px;">
        <div class="ls-thumbnail-inner">
            <div class="ls-thumbnail-slide-container">
                <div class="ls-thumbnail-slide" style="height: 80px; margin-left: 0px;">
                    <a href="#" class="ls-thumb-1" style="width: 299px; height: 80px;">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/slider-buttons-background.jpg" class="ls-thumb-active" style="opacity: 1;"> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ls-thumb-1').addClass("newclass");
 });
```

(I use this script in WordPress, so I have to add jQuery instead of $, other scripts are working well)

Adding a class to an id works also well.

Thank you for your tips.

Comment: @Satpal Probably that using an id selector in conjunction with `addClass` works for him

Comment: I'm guessing the ls-thumb-1 class does not exist when the page is loaded. Probably it is being created by some other script. That means there's no element to add your "newclass" to at document.ready

Comment: Your code adds the class `newclass` to an element which has the class `ls-thumb-1`. Is it that you want to do, or as you initially state, add the `ls-thumb-1` class to an element?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I´ve tried the script to add a class to an div with an id-selector. In this case, it works well.

Comment: Are you using some plugin something like carousel or something else?

Comment: yes, i want to append the class: old: ls-thumb-1 new: ls-thumb-1 newclass

Comment: i use the layerslider plugin

Comment: Check your browser console for the error you're getting.

Comment: there is no error in the console

Comment: Add this to your ready handler to see if the elements are present at load time: `console.log(jQuery('.ls-thumb-1').length);`

Comment: @mm1975, using `layerslider` plugin is very important detail not to include in question. I will suggest you to updated question and include proper detail. Also show code where you are using the plugin.

Comment: I´ve added the log and get '0', hmm...the class is not available on load

Comment: If I add timeout to the function instead of jQuery(document).ready(function() it works!

Comment: You can also use **$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified' ....** and this would fix your bit after few more refactoring in your existing code to handle multiple time triggering of this event